# Trying to redirect a page depending on what is in the URL with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am looking to redirect a webpage if the URL is a certain URL. I can only edit the header script (which is in every webpage), but I only need to redirect the one page, so I chose to go this route.

For example, if the URL is /blog I want it to redirect to /blog-home. The problem I am having is that /blog/blogpost is also redirecting to /blog-home. I only want the one page (/blog) to redirect.

Right now I have:

```
 if(document.URL.indexOf("/blog") >= 0){ 
  window.stop();
  window.location.href = "/blog-home";
}
```

With this code, /blog redirects fine to /blog-home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [endsWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/String/endsWith) to make sure that '/blog' is the last part of the URL.

```
if(document.URL.endsWith("/blog")){ 
  window.stop();
  window.location.href = "/blog-home";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check it using a regex, consider also that it might be an additional trailing `/` after the url, it might end for example with `/blog` or `/blog/`:

```js
if(document.URL.match(/\/blog\/?$/) !== null){ 
  window.stop();
  window.location.href = "/blog-home";
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This works great. I ended up putting the other answer in because I think it would make more sense to my client.

Answer (score 0):

Split the URL on `/` characters and use an equality test on the last part.

```
var split = document.URL.split("/");
if (split[split.length-1] == "blog") {
    window.stop();
    window.location.href = "/blog-home";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

window.location gives you the current url path
window.location.origin gives you the base path thus you do the following :

```
if(window.location === window.location.origin +"/blog" ) {
    window.stop();
    window.location.href = "/blog-home"
}
```